# Create a Observable that delays the next value

Tags: observable, reactive-extensions-js, rxjs

I'm trying to create an observable using RxJS that does what is pictured.

[image: Expected observable mapping]

- Grabs a value and waits a fixed period of time before getting the
  next one.
- The next one will be the last value emitted in the period of the
  wait, skipping the rest.
- If an wait interval goes by where no value was emitted, the next one
  should be grabbed immediately as the last example of the image
  depicts.

Comment: Thank you for making a marble diagram.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
var Rx      = require('rx'),
    source  = Rx.Observable.interval(10).take(100),
    log     = console.log.bind(console);

Rx.Observable.create(function (observer) {

    var delaying = false,
        hasValue = false,
        complete = false,
        value;

    function onNext (x) {
      value = x;
      if (delaying) {
        hasValue = true;
      } else {
        sendValue();
      }
    }

    function sendValue () {
      observer.onNext(value);
      if (complete) {
        observer.onCompleted();
      } else {
        setTimeout(callback, 1000); // exercise for the reader. Use a scheduler.
      }
      delaying = true;
    }

    function callback () {
      if (hasValue) {
        hasValue = false;
        sendValue();
      } else {
        delaying = false;
      }
    }

    return source.subscribe(
        onNext,
        observer.onError.bind(observer),
        function () {
          if (hasValue) {
            complete = true;
          } else {
            observer.onCompleted();
          }
        }
      );
  })
  .subscribe(log);
```

Comment: Great solution. Works perfectly.
Would it be possible to convert this into a LINQ operator as well?
So we'd have something like this:

`source.delayNext(other).subscribe()`

So that we could use the `other` values to dynamically choose the time to delay the next item.

Comment: Absolutely. You should take a look at the Rx source and see how to do that. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is Christopher's solution modified into a operator.

The `throttleImmediate` operator only stores the latest value from the source until the given selector completes. It fires the cached value, if existent, right after each completion.
It is best suited to use when the selector has side effects (e.g. an animation).

```
var Rx  = require('rx'),
source  = Rx.Observable.interval(10).take(500),
log     = console.log.bind(console);

Rx.Observable.prototype.throttleImmediate = function (selector) {
    var source = this;

    return Rx.Observable.create(function (observer) {

        var delaying = false,
            hasValue = false,
            complete = false,
            value;

        function onNext (x) {
          value = x;
          if (delaying) {
            hasValue = true;
          } else {
            sendValue();
          }
        }

        function sendValue () {
          delaying = true;
          selector(value).subscribe(
            observer.onNext.bind(observer),
            observer.onError.bind(observer),
            function(){
              if (hasValue) {
                hasValue = false;
                sendValue();
              } else {
                delaying = false;
              }
            }
          );
        }

        return source.subscribe(
            onNext,
            observer.onError.bind(observer),
            function () {
              if (hasValue) {
                complete = true;
              } else {
                observer.onCompleted();
              }
            }
          );
      });
};

source
  .throttleImmediate(function(data){
    var delay;

    if(data%2==0)
      delay=500;
    else
      delay=1000;

    return Rx.Observable.timer(delay).map(function(){ return data; });
  })
  .subscribe(log)
```

This comes in handy while back pressuring sources where the value to delay is only known by the selector.

**Example**:
Given the question's marble diagram.

Let's suppose the first source are ajax calls with html data to display, `ajaxPages` that originated from clicks on a navbar.
And we want render them along with an entry animation, `animatePage`, whose duration is dynamic.

```
ajaxPages.throttleImmediate(animatePage).subscribe();
```

Here we animate the pages with the values from the source, skipping all the values that are emitted during the period of animation except the latest.

In practice, what we get is an stream that ignores clicks that are shortly followed by other clicks and are useless to show to the user since they would animate in, and immediately animate out.

Comment: The `until` post fix is usually used in association with auto-disposal (`takeUntil`). I'd suggest using something other than that, as `delayUntil` sounds like you want to delay a value until the "animatePage" observable yields. In reality, the operator could be more accurately described as `throttle`. However, an operator by this name already exists in Rx. That operator should REALLY be named `debounce`, but we can't really do anything about it at this point. Therefore, I would go with something like `thottleImmediate`.

Comment: The `throttle` operator is a sad story, but it's used too much to rename it at this point... :/